# Delete dir with nAnt and exclude sub folder?

Tags: nant

I'm looking for my build to delete the contents of a directory without touching a certain folder.  Below is what I'm trying, and it even looks wrong to me...aside from the fact that it bombs when I run it.  Do I need to be deleting the contents of the dir explicitly and at the same time exclude my Reports folder?

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
      <fileset dir="${PublishLocation}" >
        <exclude name="**Reports**"/>
      </fileset>
    </delete>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be:

```
<delete>
  <fileset basedir="${PublishLocation}">
    <include name="**/*"/>
    <exclude name="**/Reports/**/*" />
  </fileset>
</delete>
```

Please notice the following:

- `includeemptydirs="true"` is default
- The attribute for `fileset` is `basedir` instead of `dir`
- if you specify `<exclude name="**/Reports/**" />` instead of `<exclude name="**/Reports/**/*" />` all files named `Reports` are kept as well

Comment: Thanks to much.  Moving the reports was making the build to the server take over 60 minutes, not it's down to 2.  Cheers!